# How else is Girls' Generation "Into the New World" related to Dvorak's Symphony No. 9 in E minor, "From the New World"?

Tags: classical-music, pop-music, world-music

I've been listening to [*Into the New World* (song)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_New_World_(song)) since 2008. But I didn't realize until today that [Mindblown. : SNSD](https://old.reddit.com/r/SNSD/comments/11womq/mindblown/)

> the [opening phrase in ITNW](http://youtu.be/0k2Zzkw_-0I?t=48s)
> contains the same sequence of notes as the [first theme from the finale of Dvorak's Symphony No. 9](http://youtu.be/89jOPAGJq-M?t=15s), but with a different rhythm.

Are there any other similarities? INTW's composer, Kenzie, was a ["music production and engineering (MP&E) major at Berklee". She "had some basic musical knowledge because I played in a band before Berklee and have a classical piano background."](https://college.berklee.edu/news/4742/alumni-profile-kenzie-yeonjung-kim-99)

[image]

Comment: The premise of this question is interesting! With that said, though, I don't think this question really works within the format of this site. Identifying similarities is very subjective, unfortunately (Stack Exchange wants questions that can be answered definitively and correctly). Music: P&E is a question and answer site, but not a forum for discussion. You may wish to try asking in the [chat], though, or even [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) instead *if* they'll take it.

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says that "technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof" is on topic; Obviously this question is a little different, comparing two specific works, but is it still essentially along the same lines?

Comment: @user45266 similarity is not necessarily subjective.  For example, there is nothing subjective about the similarity identified in the question, is there?

Comment: Another example that I recently encountered that absolutely blew my mind: Queen's "We Are the Champions" chorus is the opening of Stravinsky's "Rite of Spring."

Comment: @phoog My concern is that the field of potential answers is so large that it's basically a matter of opinion as to what should count as a similarity. "Both works have a vowel in their title" is a correct and valid answer to the question asked. So are things like "they both have melody, harmony, and rhythm". Or "the two works tend to return to their tonic chords".

Comment: And for what it's worth, the question's premise isn't verifiable as an *intended* similarity either, it's just something someone online noticed. What prevents me from answering that both songs bear resemblance to a 30-second segment of the soundtrack to obscure 1938 horror film *The Bloody Anvil*? I made up that fake movie as an example, but I'm trying to illustrate that I don't think this question can really be answered in a correct way. In my subjective opinion, maybe the *Anvil* tie-in is something worth mentioning, and that's of the same proof standard that the linked similarity is!

Comment: It would be different if there was a way to isolate certain similarities by their relevance or significance or something, but at the moment since that cannot be done here *(or at least I don't see how it could be done)*, **this question is at its core a creative freewriting prompt**. I just don't think this post works on a question and answer website.

Comment: @user45266 look at the title of the song.  Notice how the melody is not just similar, but (ignoring rhythm) identical.  Do you really think that could be an accident?

Comment: @Richard Wow! I didn't realize that either. If anyone's interested, see https://youtu.be/ZzuQZXTpNmg.

Comment: @phoog I noticed that, and I'm aware that it's very likely that this was intended. But that doesn't really matter to me. Even if it's *proven* to be an intentional allusion I still think the question's too open-ended. There is no bound to the number of ways two pieces of music can be comparatively described, and thus there are infinitely many similarities between the two pieces of music. It seems similar to "What are some examples of X kind of music?", which IIRC isn't kosher? Actually, there might even be a case for *not helpful to future readers* - what musical problem are we solving here?